# angular2 display after each loop

Tags: angular

This might be the dumbest question ever but please keep in mind that I am very very new to angular2.

In angular2 how can I make a value render after each loop. I don't want to use *ngFor. Just a loop like this

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/categories/categories.component.html'
})
ngOnInit(){  
    export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
        for(var i=0; i<this.categories.length; i++) {
           count=i;
        }
    }
}
```

After each loop update the html.

```
Loop number {{ count }}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of some input data and expected output? Besides that, the `ngOnInit()` method must be inside the component...

Comment: @OliverHader sorry can edit my previous comment. I don't have any input, just a call to an api.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `*ngFor`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm just going to copy and paste what I told lenny in the answer. So what I have is a list of categories (parent), each parent category has a list of child categories. I connect to the API, retrieve the list and display the name of the parent categories. So far using ngFor I can do that. Now when I display the list of parent categories, I want to retrieve the count of how many child categories each parent categories has. To do this I need to reconnect to the API using the parent category_id, to retrieve the count of the child cats. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's the use case for this, but here you go:

**categories.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/categories/categories.component.html'
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
    private count: number;

    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnInit(){  
        for(var i=0; i<this.categories.length; i++) {
           this.count=i;
           this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**categories.component.html**

```
<div>Loop number {{ count }}</div>
```

You shouldn't do it. Why not using `*ngFor`?

Comment: Ok may be I'm using the wrong approach here. And Like i said very very new to this. Literally weeks odl. 
So what I have is a list of categories (parent), each parent category has a list of child categories. I connect to the API, retrieve the list and display the name of the parent categories. So far using ngFor I can do that. Now when I display the list of parent categories, I want to retrieve the count of how many child categories each parent categories has. To do this I need to reconnect to the API using the parent category_id, to retrieve the count of the child cats. How can this be done?

Comment: Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question or create a new one and show what you have tried so far, the component that displays the parent categories etc.

Comment: Did you read the [tour of heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)? It's similar to what you are trying to do, loading a list of data from a web api and display it. Good to start with when you are new to angular 2.